# Nextjs with material-ui: Prop `className` did not match. Server:

Tags: material-ui, next.js

I'm creating a NextJS app that uses React Material-Ui and I'm getting the `Prop 'className' did not match.` error, even though I changed my `_app.tsx` and `_document.tsx` according to the documentation.

My `_app.tsx`:

```js
// pages/_app.tsx
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-props-no-spreading */
import { FC, useEffect } from 'react';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { defaultTheme as theme  } from '../src/themes';

const MyApp: FC<AppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
        const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
        if (jssStyles) {
            jssStyles?.parentElement?.removeChild(jssStyles);
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>My App</title>
                <meta
                    name="viewport"
                    content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width"
                />
            </Head>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
                <CssBaseline />
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </ThemeProvider>
        </>
    );
};

export default MyApp;
```

My `_document.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Document, {
    Html,
    Head,
    Main,
    NextScript,
    DocumentProps,
    DocumentContext,
} from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { defaultTheme as theme } from '../src/themes';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
    static getInitialProps = async (ctx: DocumentContext) => {
        const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
        const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

        ctx.renderPage = () =>
            originalRenderPage({
                enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
                    sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
            });

        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

        return {
            ...initialProps,
            // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
            styles: [
                ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
                sheets.getStyleElement(),
            ],
        };
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Html lang="en">
                <Head>
                    {/* PWA primary color */}
                    <meta
                        name="theme-color"
                        content={theme.palette.primary.main}
                    />
                    <link
                        rel="stylesheet"
                        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,800,900&display=swap"
                    />
                </Head>
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        );
    }
}
```

Browser Console Error:

```
Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "MuiBox-root MuiBox-root-10" Client: "MuiBox-root MuiBox-root-13"
div
StyledComponent@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@material-ui/styles/esm/styled/styled.js:95:22
div
Grid@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Grid/Grid.js:236:29
WithStyles@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@material-ui/styles/esm/withStyles/withStyles.js:61:25
div
Grid@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Grid/Grid.js:236:29
WithStyles@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@material-ui/styles/esm/withStyles/withStyles.js:61:25
div
Container@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Container/Container.js:85:17
WithStyles@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@material-ui/styles/esm/withStyles/withStyles.js:61:25
div
StyledComponent@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@material-ui/styles/esm/styled/styled.js:95:22
div
StyledComponent@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@material-ui/styles/esm/styled/styled.js:95:22
Home@webpack-internal:///./pages/index.tsx:93:17
ThemeProvider@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@material-ui/styles/esm/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider.js:42:18
MyApp@webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.tsx:37:19
ErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay/lib/internal/ErrorBoundary.js:26:47
ReactDevOverlay@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay/lib/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:86:20
Container@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:254:20
AppContainer@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:750:18
Root@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:889:19
```

I just can't figure out what's happening. Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you have any luck resolving this? I believe this issue is causing a FOUC in my project.

Comment: What versions of MUI and Next.js are you using? I was experiencing this too but I think I changed versions and I can confirm that it went away for me using `"next": "11.1.0",` and `"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",`,

Comment: I posted the solution that worked for me (using the same version as 'A Webb')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting 'reactStrictMode' to false inside next.config.js seems to solve the issue

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: false,
}
```

I don't really know why that's the case. If anyone knows, feel free to explain in the comments

Comment: I have the same issue with NextJS 11 and Storybook/Tailwind. We use a prefix for our storybook lib, and in our app, we have "className did not match..." and setting reactStrictMode: false in next.config.js solves the problem. Very mysterious.

Comment: Same problem on NextJS 12.

Comment: This worked for me until I refreshed the page a few times. Odd.

Comment: In my case setting it to true worked. [Found this config in MUI's Next example](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/next.config.js)

Comment: I can confirm that using `next: "12.3.4"`, `mui: "latest"`, `react: "18.2.0"` this does solve the problem, why though? No idea. Tried all possible solutions throughout the web, followed official mui example for migrations projects (v4 to v5) and nothing else worked.

Answer (score 4):

Only this worked for me https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7322#issuecomment-987086391

```
import React from "react";

const ClientOnly = ({ children, ...delegated }) => {

  const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setHasMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!hasMounted) return null

  return (
    <React.Fragment {...delegated}>
      {children}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default ClientOnly
```

wrap the form ->

```
<ClientOnly>
     <SomeComponnet/>
</ClientOnly>
```

Comment: that was a good answer thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Next.js supports lazy loading React components with next/dynamic. In the main Layout component you can add this wrapper and export it.

In Layout.jsx

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
```

now wrap your export component with dynamic as below

```
export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(Layout), { ssr: false })
```

now this component can delay hydration until the Suspense boundary is resolved.